# why material-ui does not works inside Router (from react-router)

Tags: react-router, material-ui

I try to use material-ui with react-router.
That example works well:

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';    
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import lightBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';


render((
  <div>

    **<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme)}>**
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Authenticated}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </Route>
        {accountRoutes()}
      </Router>
    **</MuiThemeProvider>**
  </div>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Notice that MuiThemeProvider is wraping all other components.

Then I tried MuiThemeProvider to move to inside of Router. Like that:

```
render((
  <div>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      **<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme)}>**
        <Route path="/" component={Authenticated}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </Route>
        {accountRoutes()}
      **</MuiThemeProvider>**
    </Router>
  </div>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

and i've got an error

```
warning.js:36 Warning: Failed context type: The context `muiTheme` is marked as required in `Paper`, but its value is `undefined`.
in Paper (created by Accounts)
in div (created by Accounts)
in div (created by Flexbox)
in Flexbox (created by Accounts)
in Accounts (created by Authenticated)
in Authenticated (created by RouterContext)
in RouterContext (created by Router)
in Router
in div

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined
at Paper.render (Paper.js:96)
at ReactCompositeComponent.js:796
at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
at ...
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you tell how you initiate `getMuiTheme` and `lightBaseTheme`. The reason is your `muiTheme` gets `undefined` instead of proper theme object.

Comment: `import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';`

`import lightBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme`


It works in first example and does not works in second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem and resolving. Router component wants to see Route inside him. I decided to change my code and error is gone.

```
const AuthenticatedMui = () => {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme)}>
      <Authenticated />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
};

render((
  <div>
<Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={AuthenticatedMui }>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </Route>
        {accountRoutes()}
      </Router>
    </div>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have created AuthenticatedMui and used it instead of Authenticated component.